# Returning dict from dict comprehension of nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
my_list = [ [1,2], [2,3], [3,4] ]

# my attempt
output = { {'a':k[0], 'b':k[1]} for k in my_list }

#desired output
[ {a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:3}, {a:3,b:4} ]
```

Is there a way to get the dict comprehension to return a dict, with multiple keys?

Comment: You need a list comprehension instead of dict comp `[{'a':k[0], 'b':k[1]} for k in my_list]` since the final output is a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to do this :

```
output = [ {'a':k[0], 'b':k[1]} for k in my_list ]
#        ^                                       ^
```

which we call a list-comprehension in python.

Answer (score 3):

Your outer structure ought to be a list for your output, and you are incorrectly attempting to perform a *set comprehension* as opposed to a list comprehension. This fails because set elements must be hashable, and dicts are not as they are mutable. Additionally, you can unpack the list items to be a bit more clear in this case.

```
>>> [dict(a=x, b=y) for x, y in my_list]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [ [1,2], [2,3], [3,4] ]
[dict(zip(['a', 'b'], x)) for x in my_list]
```